# coreML Error computing NN outputs -1, IOAF code -536870211

Tags: swift, tensorflow, coreml, coremltools

I am trying to verify my "port" of google's DeepLabV3 to coreML. I converted the model (excluding the final bilinear resize) using tfcoreml. My test app crashes on device at:

```
let options = MLPredictionOptions()
options.usesCPUOnly = false
let outFeatures = try! self.segmentModel.prediction(from: input,options: options)
```

with the following error:

```
2018-07-10 19:25:02.017634-0500 VisionDetection[5608:858692] Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. Internal Error (IOAF code -536870211)
2018-07-10 19:25:02.351176-0500 VisionDetection[5608:858644] [coreml] Error computing NN outputs -1
```

I've been unable to find any information on IOAF code -536870211.
It does run (albeit very slowly) if I set usesCPUOnly = true, but I am going to need to use the gpu to get the speed up to a usable level.

Any information would be appreciated. I have an iPhone 6 running 11.3, and Xcode 9.4

Update:

I've been able to find information on IOAF code -536870211, it is a memory allocation problem. I guess this one might just not fit on the GPU?

Comment: How large are your input images? The iPhone 6 does have only 1 GB of RAM. However, I recently ported DeepLabv3+ to Metal and it runs fine with 513x513 inputs (but I only tried on iPhone 7 and later). Also see this other repo of a CoreML DeepLabv3+ model https://github.com/seantempesta/keras-deeplab-v3-plus

Comment: 32x32 :/ i think there might be something wrong with my virtual environments or tfcoreml install, the link you shared worked for me. I just put the path to the  google-provided-frozen-pb into the tfcoreml converter, so I don't really have a deep understanding of the network or the conversion process in this specific instance

Comment: Does the TF model actually work OK with 32x32 images? I know the frozen graph from Google actually pads the images with zeros if they're smaller than 513x513, but the Core ML graph may not. Did you try a 513x513 image with your Core ML model?

Comment: I mean it worked, but theres not much to that can be segmented in a 32x32 image. I will try padding with zeros up to 513x513. I specified the input shape to be (1,32,32,3) in tfcoreml, and the resulting mlmodel expects a 32x32 color image at the input. Are you suggesting that I specify the input size to be 513x513 at the conversion step?

Comment: Dunno. But I'd be surprised if tfcoreml kept the padding stuff in the Core ML model.